# Using Microsoft.FSharpLu to serialize JSON to a stream

Tags: json, serialization, f#

I've been using the `Newtonsoft.Json` and `Newtonsoft.Json.Fsharp` libraries to create a new `JSON` serializer and stream to a file.  I like the ability to stream to a file because I'm handling large files and, prior to streaming, often ran into memory issues.

I stream with a simple fx:

```
open Newtonsoft.Json
open Newtonsoft.Json.FSharp 
open System.IO

let writeToJson (path: string) (obj: 'a) : unit =
    let serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj)
    let fileStream = new StreamWriter(path)
    let serializer = new JsonSerializer()

    serializer.Serialize(fileStream, obj)

    fileStream.Close()
```

This works great.  My problem is that the `JSON` string is then absolutely cluttered with stuff I don't need.  For example,

```
let m = 
    [
        (1.0M, None)
        (2.0M, Some 3.0M)
        (4.0M, None)
    ]

let makeType (tup: decimal * decimal option) = {FieldA = fst tup; FieldB = snd tup}

let y = List.map makeType m

Default.serialize y

val it : string =
  "[{"FieldA": 1.0},
    {"FieldA": 2.0,
     "FieldB": {
        "Case": "Some",
        "Fields": [3.0]
    }},
    {"FieldA": 4.0}]"
```

If this is written to a `JSON` and read into `R`, there are nested dataframes and any of the `Fields` associated with a `Case` end up being a `list`:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)

q <- fromJSON("default.json")

x <- 
    q %>%
    flatten()

x

> x
  FieldA FieldB.Case FieldB.Fields
1      1        <NA>          NULL
2      2        Some             3
3      4        <NA>          NULL
> sapply(x, class)
       FieldA   FieldB.Case FieldB.Fields 
    "numeric"   "character"        "list"
```

I don't want to have to handle these things in `R`.  I can do it but it's annoying and, if there are files with many, many columns, it's silly.

This morning, I started looking at the [`Microsoft.FSharpLu.Json` documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/fsharplu/wiki/fsharplu.json).  This library has a `Compact.serialize` function.  Quick tests suggest that this library will eliminate the need for nested dataframes and the `list`s associated with any `Case` and `Field` columns.  For example:

```
Compact.serialize y

val it : string =
  "[{
    "FieldA": 1.0
    },
  {
    "FieldA": 2.0,
    "FieldB": 3.0
  },
  {
    "FieldA": 4.0
  }
  ]"
```

When this string is read into `R`,

```
q <- fromJSON("compact.json")

x <- q
x
> x
  FieldA FieldB
1      1     NA
2      2      3
3      4     NA
> sapply(x, class)
   FieldA    FieldB 
"numeric" "numeric
```

This is much simpler to handle in R. and I'd like to start using this library.

However, I don't know if I can get the `Compact` serializer to serialize to a stream.  I see `.serializeToFile`, `.desrializeStream`, and `.tryDeserializeStream`, but nothing that can serialize to a stream.  Does anyone know if `Compact` can handle writing to a stream?  How can I make that work?

Comment: "Stuff you don't need"?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Yeah, a silly phrase, but look at the difference between the output from `Default.serialize` and `Compact.serialize` in the [`Microsoft.FSharpLu.Json` library](https://github.com/Microsoft/fsharplu/wiki/fsharplu.json).  When I read default `JSON` strings into `R`, there are `2*n` fields for every field that is an `Option` type.  With the `Compact` serialization, those additional fields disappear.

Comment: I can't "look at the difference", because I don't have these libraries installed and don't have enough time to set up a testing ground. By phrasing your question this way, you significantly reduce the set of potential respondents to those who either already have this exact setup or have too much free time.

Comment: My apologies.  I initially added the link to the documentation in both the question and comment as there is a visual comparison without needing to install the libraries.  I'll edit the question to include the difference in output.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Question edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The helper to serialize to stream is missing from the `Compact` module in FSharpLu.Json, but you should be able to do it by following the C# example from 
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm. Something along the lines:

```
let writeToJson (path: string) (obj: 'a) : unit =
    let serializer = new JsonSerializer()
    serializer.Converters.Add(new Microsoft.FSharpLu.Json.CompactUnionJsonConverter())
    use sw = new StreamWriter(path)
    use writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw)
    serializer.Serialize(writer, obj)
```